# Static List - WebMethod with EnableSession

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I am using JTable ( http://www.jtable.org/ ) in an asp.net application with forms authentication.

My web application will create a session for each user who logs in successfully.

Now, the Jtable uses a datasource which is a static list. The class where this static list resides is not static.

```
      public class UserSpecificClass
 {     
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static object PaymentsList(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string jtSorting)
    {
     //Get data from database
            using (DBDataContext context = new DBDataContext(_staticConnString))
            {
                // LINQ Query - Get userDetails including all relationships to user
                var PaymentDetails = (from t1 in context.Charges
                                      join t2 in context.Invoices on t1.InvoiceID equals t2.ID
                                      where t2.MemberID == 5
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          Related_Invoice = t1.InvoiceID,
                                          Charge_Description = t1.ChargeType.Name,
                                          Charge_Amount = t1.Amount,
                                          Amount_Paid = t1.PaidAmount,
                                          Credited = t1.CreditAmount,
                                          Last_Payment = t2.PaidAmount == 0 ? "Not Paid" : t2.PaidDate.ToString()

                                      }).ToList();

                 _mhubPayments = new List<MHubPaymentsHistory>();
                foreach (var obj in PaymentDetails)
                {
                    MHubPaymentsHistory data = new MHubPaymentsHistory(obj.Related_Invoice, obj.Charge_Description, obj.Charge_Amount,
                                                obj.Amount_Paid, obj.Credited, obj.Last_Payment);

                    _mhubPayments.Add(data);
                }

                //Return result to jTable
                return new { Result = "OK", Records = _mhubPayments, TotalRecordCount = recordCount };
    }
}
```

Now, I know that static variables and properties will be created once and available across the application domain on the server to all users... so Obviously the concern is I don't want 1 InvoicesList in the web application..

But I'm unsure that when a new user logs in, and I retrieve data from the class above, will the static object ( list in this case ) be session specific to the newly logged in user? due to the 'EnableSession = true' attribute?

ie: If 100 users log in, within each of those 100 sessions created/issued, does having the WebMethod(EnableSession) attribute attached to the object mean there be a session specific static list object for each user session? Is this basically saying that this static object will be session specific and therefor user specific?

any clarification appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any static fields.

Comment: public static object PaymentsList ?

Comment: That's a _function_.  It doesn't store any data; your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: In particular, you have any static list.

Comment: right ok.. but do you see where im coming from? With your correction in mind then, will the object returned by this method in that case be session specific to each user? I'm trying to understand the impact of the use of 'static' in this particular scenario and to be sure each user will not be seeing any other users information? Will the fact that im 'newing' up a list of new classes to return (List<MHubPaymentsHistory>() ) be suffice for ensuring the records displayed will be the logged in users? again im trying to understand the use of static with the webmethod and enable session.. thanks

Comment: I don't see why this has to be static.  jTable appears to be a jQuery plug which means it doesn't care about the source of the list (static or instance).  What do you think the advantage is using a static method over a instance method?  The reason I ask is because this seems to be an [XY Problem, that is you are asking about why your solution to a problem doesn't work, but you haven't explained the problem you are trying to solve](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static data can be problematic in this scenario because there is a single storage location across the entire application, so the value stored there can be visible between requests.  Static methods don't have the same problem - a static method is callable without an instance and cannot access instance data, but is otherwise the same as a non-static method.

Comment: Thanks bmm6o - My original question and explanation had a couple of errors and could have been misleading as SLaks obviously pointed out above but this answers my question more so in the best detail. Thanks to everyone in this post for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an attribute to a method cannot possible change how any static field behaves.

If you want to use session state, store your data in `HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: Not helpful and has little todo with what Kev was wondering about.

Comment: @MichaelViktorStarberg: Really? How do you understand the question?

Comment: I started on an answer but had problems summing it up.

Comment: SLaks: I'll upvote your answer and downvote the question as soon as am allowed to.

Comment: I've obviously misworded my whole question on this occasion :( I've reposted to SLaks previous comments with a more precise description of what im trying to understand.. should I repost the question rewording what im trying to understand in the code ive posted?

Comment: Kev: Solved. And I think SLaks can live with my -1 point. And I guess you learned to post questions better now. All in all a pretty good day.